# How can I split this comma-delimited string in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string

Hi I have been reading up about regular expressions, I have got some basic res working. I now have been trying to use Re to sort out data like this:

> "144,1231693144,26959535291011309493156476344723991336010898738574164086137773096960,26959535291011309493156476344723991336010898738574164086137773096960,1.00,4295032833,1563,2747941288,1231823695,26959535291011309493156476344723991336010898738574164086137773096960,26959535291011309493156476344723991336010898738574164086137773096960,1.00,4295032833,909,4725008"

...into a tuple but I cannot get it to work.

Can anyone explain how they would go about something like this?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "data like this"? Numeric integers? that sometimes have 3 digits? Whats the pattern you're trying to capture with a regex?

Comment: I meant to separate every integer spaced out by a comma into a list.

Answer (score 67):

You don't want regular expressions here.

```
s = "144,1231693144,26959535291011309493156476344723991336010898738574164086137773096960,26959535291011309493156476344723991336010898738574164086137773096960,1.00,4295032833,1563,2747941 288,1231823695,26959535291011309493156476344723991336010898738574164086137773096960,26959535291011309493156476344723991336010898738574164086137773096960,1.00,4295032833,909,4725008"

print s.split(',')
```

Gives you:

```
['144', '1231693144', '26959535291011309493156476344723991336010898738574164086137773096960', '26959535291011309493156476344723991336010898738574164086137773096960', '1.00
', '4295032833', '1563', '2747941 288', '1231823695', '26959535291011309493156476344723991336010898738574164086137773096960', '26959535291011309493156476344723991336010898
738574164086137773096960', '1.00', '4295032833', '909', '4725008']
```

Comment: You'll want to use `s.strip().split(',')` if this is read in from a file. The strip method gets rid of the newline and other whitespace.

Answer (score 18):

How about a list?

```
mystring.split(",")
```

It might help if you could explain what kind of info we are looking at. Maybe some background info also?

EDIT:

I had a thought you might want the info in groups of two?

then try:

```
re.split(r"\d*,\d*", mystring)
```

and also if you want them into tuples

```
[(pair[0], pair[1]) for match in re.split(r"\d*,\d*", mystring) for pair in match.split(",")]
```

in a more readable form:

```
mylist = []
for match in re.split(r"\d*,\d*", mystring):
    for pair in match.split(",")
        mylist.append((pair[0], pair[1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Question is a little vague.

```
list_of_lines = multiple_lines.split("\n")
for line in list_of_lines:
    list_of_items_in_line = line.split(",")
    first_int = int(list_of_items_in_line[0])
```

etc.