# Converting a text file to a list

Tags: python, list

I have the following text file:

```
"""['    Hoffa remains      Allen Iverson      Bill Cosby      WWE Payback results           Juneteenth shooting      Miss Utah flub      Octopus pants      Magna Carta Holy Grail      China supercomputer      Sibling bullying  ']"""
```

I would like to create a list from it and apply a function to each name

this is my code so far:

```
listing = open(fileName, 'r')
lines = listing.read().split(',')
for line in lines:
    #Function
```

Comment: You're splitting the text using `,` as the delimiter, but it looks like six spaces or would be more appropriate for your file.

Comment: I don't see any commas in your input text. Are the `"""['` characters literally part of your input file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strip out character like `"""[']` first from the start and end of the string using `str.strip`, now split the resulting string at six spaces(`' '*6`). Splitting returns a list, but some items still have traling and leading white-spaces, you can remove them using `str.strip` again.

```
with open(fileName) as f:
    lis =  [x.strip() for x in f.read().strip('\'"[]').split(' '*6)]
    print lis
...     
['Hoffa remains', 'Allen Iverson', 'Bill Cosby', 'WWE Payback results', 'Juneteenth shooting', 'Miss Utah flub', 'Octopus pants', 'Magna Carta Holy Grail', 'China supercomputer', 'Sibling bullying']
```

Applying function to the above list:

List comprehension:

```
[func(x) for x in lis]
```

map:

```
map(func, lis)
```

Comment: Is there a way to apply a function to each name now?

Comment: @user2493744 Yes, you can use either map or list comprehension. see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would first refer you to some other similar posts: [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864485/how-can-i-split-this-comma-delimited-string-in-python)

And you can't use a coma here you don't have a coma between the data you wan't to separate. This function splits the string you have into substring depending on the delimiter you gave it: a coma ','.

Comment: this is a parsed text file, which won't give me commas