# Define a function with dynamic arguments, keyword arguments from user and print them

Tags: python-3.x, function, keyword-argument

**Code:**

```
def myFun(*args, **kwargs):
    print("args: ", args)
    print("kwargs: ", kwargs)
args = input("Enter args: ")
kwargs = input("Enter kwargs: ")
myFun(args,kwargs)
```

**Output:**

```
Enter args: 1,2,3,4
Enter kwargs: a=5,b=6,c=7
args:  ('1,2,3,4', 'a=5,b=6,c=7')
kwargs:  {}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here the **expected output** is:

```
args: (1,2,3,4)

kwargs: {'a':5,'b':6,'c':7}
```

I am getting the output not as the expected output.

Comment: Why are you expecting that output? You're not doing anything with the user input - no [splitting on commas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5864485/4518341), no [converting the `kwargs` string to a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12739911/4518341), and no [converting strings to ints](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7368789/4518341).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list and dictionary comprehension to parse the `input` of the users to be list to args and dictionary to kwargs and then unpacked them into `myFun`.

```
def myFun(*args, **kwargs):
    print("args: ", args)
    print("kwargs: ", kwargs)

args = [int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in input("Enter args: ").split(",")]
kwargs = {i.strip().split("=")[0]: int(i.strip().split("=")[1]) if i.strip().split("=")[1].isdigit() else i.strip().split("=")[1] for i in input("Enter kwargs: ").split(",")}

myFun(*args, **kwargs)
```

Entered

```
Enter args: 1,2,3,4
Enter kwargs: a=5,b=6,c=7
```

Output

```
args:  (1, 2, 3, 4)
kwargs:  {'a': 5, 'b': 6, 'c': 7}
```

Comment: The value in the dictionary should be int not str.

Comment: Edited the code to convert numbers to int in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

So there are a few things here to note, you args are coming out as strings because they are being passed as strings.  `kwargs` and `args` are variable names, but `*args` and `**kwargs` are not. So what you're trying to do is probably something like:

```
def parseArgs(inputString):
    return(inputString.split(','))
def parseKWargs(inputString):
    d = {}
    for element in parseArgs(inputString):
        current = element.split('=')
        d[current[0]] = current[1]
    return(d)
def myFun(*args, **kwargs):
    print("args: ", args)
    print("kwargs: ", kwargs)
args = parseArgs(input("Enter args: "))
kwargs = parseKWargs(input("Enter kwargs: "))

myFun(*args, **kwargs)
```

*kwargs* needs to be a dictionary and "passed by reference" I believe is the correct way to word that. Hope this helps.

Thanks wjandrea for the good catches

Comment: Check the output. This isn't quite correct. I'm getting `args:  (['1', '2', '3', '4'],)` and `kwargs:  {'a': '5', 'b': '6', 'c': '7'}`

Comment: BTW, don't use `input` as a variable name cause it shadows the builtin `input()`. Also `argparse` is the name of a standard library module, so you may want to use a different name to avoid confusion, but nbd.

Comment: @wjandrea is absolutely correct, using input is a bad practice; only meant for demonstrative purposes, and I will update the example to return multiple arguments instead of an argument list momentarily.